# Humidification Problem

Tags: pressure, physical-chemistry, evaporation, humidity

**Humidification**

> Imagine that water is evaporating into initially dry air in the closed
>   vessel shown schematically in Fig. 8.1-1(a). The vessel is isothermal
>   at 25 C, so the water’s vapor pressure is 3.2 kPa. This vessel has
>   0.8 l of water with 150 cm2 of surface area in a total volume of 19.2 l. After 3 min, the air is five percent saturated. What is the mass
>   transfer coefficient? How long will it take to reach ninety percent
>   saturation?

It's a fairly simple question but I'm kind of stuck on the technicalities, so to calculate the flux it should just be [(Conc. of water vapor) *(volume of Air)]/[Surface area of interface * 180 seconds], but how do I calculate the concentration of water vapor from the given information?

[image]

The answer starts with this: $$N_1=\frac{\text{Vapor concentration}\cdot\text{Air Volume}}{\text{Liquid Area}\cdot\text{Time}}$$

Ok, so far this makes sense, the solution then goes on to do this:
$$N_1=\frac{0.05\cdot(\frac{3.2}{101})\cdot(\frac{1mol}{22.4liters})\cdot(\frac{273}{298})(18.4liters)}{(150cm^2)(180sec)}$$

I understand the denominator but the numerator I'm not sure of, overall there are 18.4/22.4 mol of gas and 5% of that will be water vapor, I get that. But what's with the temperature and pressure adjustment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider the temperature, because $22.4\,$l/mol is the value for 0°C, and it will be greater at higher temperature.

You need to consider the pressure, because 5% saturation does not mean, that 5% of the gas is water, but that the amount of water is 5% of the maximal amount possible at this temperature. The maximal amount is given by the vapor pressure of 3.2 kPa (it would get bigger for higher temperature and get the full air pressure only at 100°C)